# Weebly Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, syntax-error, weebly, unexpected-token

I am trying to implement my unity app for my Weebly site. I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf-yNlMLcqA

I have these two codes:

1.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-us">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <title>Unity WebGL Player | LearningEffective</title>
 <script 
 src="https://pamaentertainment.weebly.com/files/theme/Build/UnityLoader.js"> 
 </script>
 <script>
 var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", 
 "https://pamaentertainment.weebly.com/files/theme/Build/Learning Effective 
 online.json");
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 720px; height: 1280px; margin: auto"> 
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

2.

```
{
"companyName": "pama",
"productName": "LearningEffective",
"dataUrl": "https://pamaentertainment.weebly.com/files/theme/Build/LearningEffectiveonline.data.unityweb",
"asmCodeUrl": "https://pamaentertainment.weebly.com/files/theme/Build/LearningEffectiveonline.asm.code.unityweb",
"asmMemoryUrl": "https://pamaentertainment.weebly.com/files/theme/Build/LearningEffectiveonline.asm.memory.unityweb",
"asmFrameworkUrl": "https://pamaentertainment.weebly.com/files/theme/Build/LearningEffectiveonline.asm.framework.unityweb",
"TOTAL_MEMORY": 268435456,
"graphicsAPI": ["WebGL 2.0", "WebGL 1.0"],
"webglContextAttributes": {"preserveDrawingBuffer": false},
"backgroundUrl": "https://pamaentertainment.weebly.com/files/theme/Build/LearningEffectiveonline.jpg",
"splashScreenStyle": "Dark",
"backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
}
```

When I try to load the page where Weebly's embed code is, Chrome pops up a window with this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using has a space. The correct URL doesn't have one.

Change this:

```
var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", 
"https://pamaentertainment.weebly.com/files/theme/Build/Learning Effectiveonline.json");
```

To this:

```
var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", 
"https://pamaentertainment.weebly.com/files/theme/Build/LearningEffectiveonline.json");
```

Comment: I fixed the URL but then I got this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a web server.

IIS - in file web.config:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".unityweb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
```

Apache - in file .htaccess:

```
AddType application/octet-stream unityweb
AddType application/json json
```

https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0.466784/

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1397472/webgl-build-when-uploaded-gives-me-this-error-unca.html